# Save hidden field to server?

Tags: jquery, html, save

I have a beginner's question: I wrote a javascript function which 'records' the elapsed time between two events. Now I want to save the reaction-time for a number of trials on a server. This will be an online experiment and - ideally - I want to 'pick up' the individual output files for each participant who did the experiment.

I now write my desired output to a hidden field. But how can I access it later when once it's online?
And would this be possible with one of the website builder tools (I know I can add own html/js elements).

Would be great if you could help me with this.

Below an example, my variable t1t2 is simply the reaction time which I want to save.

```
<input type="hidden" id="input_RT" value="">   

t1t2.push(reac);
console.log(t1t2);
$("#input_RT").val(t1t2);
```

Comment: You'll need some sort of data storage at the server (e.g. a database like MySQL or pgSQL), and some script which will process your form when it's submitted to the server (PHP, Node.js, Ruby, Python - whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple web service that stores data to database of your choice.
Then use JQuery Ajax or any other ajax call to send data to your exposed web method